# How to resize the device_vector after I use the unique_by_key?

Tags: cuda, resize, unique, distance, thrust

This is the code I used.
But it can not work.
something wrong with the new_end;

```
thrust::device_vector<int> keys;
thrust::device_vector<int> values;
// after initialization.

pair<int*, int*> new_end;
new_end = thrust::unique_by_key(keys.begin(), keys.end(), values.begin());
keys.resize(thrust::distance(keys.begin,new_end.first));
values.resize(thrust::distance(values.begin(), new_end.right));
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of problems with this code.

1. `thrust::unique_by_key` will return a pair of iterators that are
   appropriate for the vector types used.  In this case you are using
   `thrust::device_vector<int>` so the iterator types returned are
   `thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator` not `int*` (I guess you
   probably picked up `int*` from the example given in the
   [documentation](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html#gaf39eb3a25abb1ecc5cc2cf1110405261).)

   So instead of:

   ```
   pair<int*, int*> new_end;
   ```

   try:

   ```
   thrust::pair<thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator, thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator> new_end;
   ```
2. `new_end.right` doesn't make sense.  Perhaps you meant `new_end.second` ?
3. You cannot use `keys.begin`  I guess you meant `keys.begin()`

The above changes should at least allow the code you've shown to compile.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am a newer in CUDA programming. Thanks.

Comment: But, after I rewrote the code as you advised. There is still some problem with this line:         values.resize(thrust::distance(values.begin(), new_end.right));

Comment: Yes, I told you **you cannot use `new_end.right`**.  Try `new_end.second`.  Did you read my answer?